# How to create two type of user and custome auth url in next auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I I'm building a full-stack shopping website using Nextjs, I have two types of users one for customers and one for website admin.
I use mysql2 and Sequelize for handling the database, Admin and user have a separate table in the database.

I use `next auth` for Admin and User authentication.
I want to separate `api auth`  for each of them
like:
Admin => `/api/admin/login`
Users => `/api/user/login`
I built Admin auth already but I got an Error for auth, how do separate Admin Auth and User Auth `api rout` and sessions in Next Auth:

AdminLogin client pagecode:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

const AdminLogin = (props) => {
  const handleRequest = async () => {
    const data = {
      email: emailRef.current.value,
      password: passRef.current.value,
    };

    const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      redirect: false,
      email: emailRef.current.value,
      password: passRef.current.value,
    });

    console.log(result);
  };

  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passRef = useRef();
  const remindeRef = useRef();

  return (
    <main className="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
      <div
        className="row justify-content-center align-items-center"
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <div className="col-sm-3 col-11">
          <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              handleRequest();
            }}
          >
            <div
              className="position-relative text-center"
              style={{ height: "150px" }}
            >
              <Image
                className="mb-4"
                src="/assets/images/logo.png"
                width={100}
                height={143}
                alt="benizh"
                unoptimized
              />
            </div>
            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal text-center">ورود ادمین</h1>

            <div className="form-floating mb-3">
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control text-end"
                id="floatingInput"
                placeholder="name@example.com"
                style={{ direction: "ltr" }}
                ref={emailRef}
              />
              <label htmlFor="floatingInput">پست الکترونیک</label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-floating mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control text-end"
                id="floatingPassword"
                placeholder="Password"
                style={{ direction: "ltr" }}
                ref={passRef}
              />
              <label htmlFor="floatingPassword">رمز عبور</label>
            </div>

            {/* <div className="checkbox mb-3">
              <label>
                <span>مرا بخاطر بسپار</span>
                <span className="ps-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" ref={remindeRef} />
                </span>
              </label>
            </div> */}
            <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
              ورود
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default AdminLogin;
```

Admin api route code:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import Admin from "../../../../models/admin";
import { verifyPassword } from "../../../../utils/hash-p";

export default NextAuth({
  //   jwt: {
  //     maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
  //   },
  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const admin = await Admin.findOne({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });

        if (!admin) {
          throw new Error("No user found");
        }

        const isValid = await verifyPassword(
          credentials.password,
          admin.password
        );

        if (!isValid) {
          throw new Error("Wrong Password");
        }

        return { email: admin.email };
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

I used [Next Auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) official site to built this.

Comment: do u have two different ui to login? one for user one for admin login?

Comment: Yes, I have, But I started whit admin auth

Comment: @AmirHossein
Were you able to make different session for two different users ?
I'm also trying to do for admin and dealer users.